# java Matcher returns the whole match

Tags: java, regex

I have a `regex`  to get quizid from a string like `completed"<a target="_blank" href="/Quiz/Details/290">` . this is my code

```
  String regex = "href=\"[^\"]+Quiz+[^\"\\d]+(\\d+)\"";
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sourceString);
  String quizid = matcher.group();
```

The regex is suppos to return `290` from my string `completed"<a target="_blank" href="/Quiz/Details/290">` but what i get is `href="/Quiz/Details/290`. i think my regex is correct but i have no idea why the whole text is returned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `Matcher#group( int )` method to grab string captured by a particular group number

so use:

```
String quizid = matcher.group(1);
```

instead of:

```
String quizid = matcher.group();
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/aB4zI0/1)